# Can I use MRDS (Microsoft Robotics Developer Studio) with C#?

Tags: c#, robotics-studio

I need to develop 3d simulation for teaching robots using MRDS and C#. Can I do this using these tools?

Comment: how can we know what do you use?

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you should be able to use MRDS and C# to create 3d simulations, even without the hardware - if I get your question correctly.

Comment: actually i want to develop 3d simulation software through which we show that our robotic arm is able to write alphabets like A,B etc.we are using csharp but i searched abt MRDS so i thought using charp and this MRDS we can make this software simulation

Answer (score 1):

MRDS primarily uses C#. It also includes a visual programming language that allows you to quickly create a simulated environment. MRDS and it's tutorials are strongly focused on differential drive mobile robotics, not robotics arms. However, it can model arms and the code demo that simulates a room full of robots has an industrial arm included. You could remove all the other robots and have a nice template to start with.

If you are flexible on giving up C#, I also reccomend taking a look at Robologix http://www.robologix.com/ . Robologix is specifically for simulating robotic arms. You can get MRDS to simulate anything, and it does use C#, but it will be an uphill battle.